# AFNetworking for ios 4.3

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Currently I am developing ios apps in 4.3 . I have been using ASIHttprequest for my all Network activities. Now I want to use AFNetworking. My problem is that I can't get the AFNetworking classes for ios 4.3. some blogs given by google search says AFNetworking 0.10 is compatible for ios 4.3 but I can get 1.0 version only.

All I want to know is whether AFNetworking has version compatible for ios 4.3, If so direct me to the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the GitHub account for AFNetworking. You should be able to find it. Switch the branch to the correct version (0.10.x) and you will be good.

Anyway, here is the link to the version directly: [Version 0.10.x](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/0.10.x)

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking is stored on Github.

You can get any commit from it's history, for example - you can select any of the tagged states for download from https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tags